# C program - Faulty scores output

Tags: c

C program. IDE used is Xcode v12.2.

The problem I am facing:

Faulty scores output. For each round, the program should output the highest and lowest scores and the average score if the player chooses to do so.

Scores output after playing for 1 round:

```
Enter 'S' to show results
Enter 'P' to play another round
Enter 'R' to return to the main menu
S
Round 0 score: 92/100
Highest score: 92/100
Lowest score: 92/100
Average score:inf
****** Player: MAX ******
```

Scores output after playing for 2 rounds:

```
Enter 'S' to show results
Enter 'P' to play another round
Enter 'R' to return to the main menu
S
Round 0 score: 95/100
Highest score: 95/100
Lowest score: 92/100
Average score:inf
****** Player: MAX ******
```

Questions:

Why is 'Round 1' shown as 'Round 0'? And what does the 'inf' mean in the average score section? How do I turn 'inf' into a numerical output? After 2 rounds, the output 'Round 2' is still shown as 'Round 0' and the 'Average score' did not change to a numerical output.

What I have tried:

```
void quiz(char name[])
{
    // function created to enclose quiz functionality apart from instructions
    int rounds = 0;
    int highest = 0;
    int lowest = INT_MAX;
    float allScore = 0;
    float avg = 0;

    int i, j, g = 0;
    //char x;
    struct struc test[MAX_TESTS];

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    for (;;)
    {
        rounds++;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++)    // generate all questions
        {
            ctm_i(&test[i]);

            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)

                if (test[i].a == test[j].a && test[i].b == test[j].b && test[i].c == test[j].c)
                    //if question is already present
                    ctm_i(&test[i]);    //then re-generate
        }
        //int ig = getchar();
        char x;
        x = getchar();
        printf("\n Are you ready? Press Enter key to continue. ");
        fflush(stdin);
        while (x != '\n') {}
        while (getchar() != '\n') {}
        //getchar();

        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            printf(                " *******************************************************************"
                "**"
                "***********\n");

            printf(                " ..................................................................."
                ".."
                "...........\n");
        }

        // Take quiz
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++)
            tcm_i(&test[i], i);

        printf(" End\n\n");

        bool done = false;
        bool unsure = true;
        bool showS = true;

        while (unsure)
        {
            unsure = false;
            puts("\n");
            if (showS)
            {
                puts(" Enter 'S' to show results");
            }
            puts(" Enter 'P' to play another round");
            //puts(" Enter 'Q' to quit");
            puts(" Enter 'R' to return to main menu");
            char choice;
            printf(" ");
            myread("%c", &choice);
            if (choice == 'r' || choice == 'R')
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else if (choice == 'S' || choice == 's')
            {
                showS = false;
                // calculate total score for current round
                g = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++)
                {
                    g += test[i].grade;    //add score of each question
                }
                allScore += g;    //add current round's score to total
                avg = allScore / rounds;    //average of all rounds

                if (g > highest)
                {
                    highest = g;
                }

                if (g < lowest)
                {
                    lowest = g;
                }

                if (rounds == 1)
                {
                    printf(" Final score: %d/100\n", g);    //display round score
                    printf(" ******Player: %s ******\n", name);
                }
                else
                {
                         //puts("Whoops! Looks like highest/lowest have not been adjusted!");
                    printf(" Round %d score: %d/100\n", rounds, g);    //display round score
                    printf(" Highest score: %d/100\n", highest);
                    printf(" Lowest score: %d/100\n", lowest);
                    printf(" Average score: %f\n", avg);
                    printf(" ******Player: %s ******\n", name);
                }
                unsure = true;
                //getchar();
            }
            else if (choice == 'P' || choice == 'p')
            {
                g = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++)
                {
                    g += test[i].grade;    //add score of each question
                }
                allScore += g;    //add current round's score to total
                if (g > highest)
                {
                    highest = g;
                }

                if (g < lowest)
                {
                    lowest = g;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                puts(" Invalid input!");
                unsure = true;
            }
        }
        if (done)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `rounds` is always 0. Dividng by 0 gives you infinity, represented by `inf`. If it is ever true `while (x != '\n')` will be an infinite loop since `x` can't change in the body of the loop. If you want `lowest` and `highest` to be based on individual grades then your code to calculate them is in the wrong place. Right now it is using the total of all grades. Your formatting is also terrible and makes your code much harder to read which can easily lead to bugs.

Comment: My apologies for the terrible formatting, I have edited it now.

Comment: Do not make substantive changes to the question after receiving answers.  Especially changes that alter the validity of your answers.  In particular, modifying the code presented to address problems described in your answers is poor form.  This is a *question & answer* site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is 'Round 1' shown as 'Round 0'?

The value of variable `rounds` is printed as the round number.  If the round number always prints as 0 then it follows that `rounds` always has value zero at the point where that `printf()` call is made.  And indeed, a look at all the appearances of that variable in your code shows that it is initialized to zero in its declaration, and then *never modified*.

> And what does the 'inf' mean in
> the average score section?

It means "infinity", and before even looking at your code, I would take it as a sign that you have somewhere used the result of dividing a non-zero floating-point number by zero.

In particular, the problem seems to be the same one as the previous: you use `rounds` as the divisor in your average score computation, and it is always zero.

> How do I turn 'inf' into a numerical
> output?

Change the faulty computation into a correct one.  Properly maintaining the value of the `rounds` variable may be enough.

> After 2 rounds, the output 'Round 2' is still shown as 'Round
> 0' and the 'Average score' did not change to a numerical output.

That's consistent with my observations above.

Comment: For the 'Round 0' problem, I have found that using ````round++;```` would be a great way to output the correct numbers. As for now, the average score output after playing for 2 rounds has changed to the addition of both the highest and lowest scores, without the division of 2. And I'm still working on this, any advice?

Comment: @TheNovice, it sounds like you are still computing the average based on the wrong number of rounds.  I am not inclined to re-analyze your code in light of the revisions, but I suspect you are incrementing `rounds` in the wrong place.

Comment: I have just modified my code according to your advice, and now it is working great.